# GCP Scheduler frequency?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks

I would like to launch a GCP instance every 10 minutes.  Google suggests that one can create a "schedule" and then attach a VM to the schedule, e.g., [per these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop).  The syntax is similar to CRON.

I do so, and GCP summarizes the schedule in human-readable form for me, which reads:

```
VM Start: Every 10 minutes, starting at 0 minutes past the hour, every hour, every day
```

I attach my VM, and sure enough, it launches regularly.  However, it launches exactly *once* an hour (at 12 minutes and 30 seconds after the hour) instead of every 10 minutes.

What is going on?  (Does the scheduler have an unspoken rule that the minimum launch frequency is an hour?)

Comment: Above your issue, I would to understand why to start the same VM every 10 minutes. Does it shut down automatically? Do you perform a job on it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I (successfully) auto-shut down the VM a minute after launch, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, the process is: GCP scheduler launches the instance; systemd runs on the VM, launching a script at startup; after about a minute, the script runs `sudo shutdown -h now`.  If I examine the cloud logs, I can see that the "ScheduledVMs" lines only occur on the hour.

Comment: I agree, that's not the root cause, but your design is weird, or old fashion. If you want to run a batch every 10 minutes, use a batch service, and not a VM service. CLoud Batch or Cloud Run Jobs are greats for that! https://cloud.google.com/batch?hl=en https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs

Comment: Using the right tool for the right job, will save time, money, effort, and unnecessary issue and bugs!

Comment: I suspect your comments are very on-point, @guillaumeblaquiere, and I'll read the links you were kind enough to include to guide me more wisely for my next project.  But for this one, I already have an instance that auto-launches, and would rather not make all the modifications necessary to containerize it, download and upload data to Google Storage, stably save logs, etc etc.  I appreciate that my approach is inelegant, but it still seems like the Google Scheduler is behaving strangely, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Scheduler in this case will run once in 10 minutes but within the constraints of the minimum frequency which is once every 1 minute. Even if you set it at “Every 10 minutes” still it will be in scope of the minimum limitation of once per minute. You might want to consider using cron job for your use case. Attached are documentations that you can use for reference.[1][2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules

[2] https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Comment: Huh?  If the minimum limit is "once per minute", then why would there be any issue running it once every 10 minutes?

I'm also unclear in what sense I should be "using cron job" here; I can't run cron job on a machine that is turned off.  Are you suggesting I should run a second machine to launch the first machine, and run a cron job on the secondary machine?